# Flexbox wont float to center

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

Working on a container containing 6 `<div>`. I can position them in the center of the container, but wont flow to the middle with the text positioned below..

Would appreciate all the help i can get.

```css
.services {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="subSection services">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="img/icon1.png">
    <h3>ICON 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="img/icon2.png">
    <h3>ICON 2</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="img/icon3.png">
    <h3>ICON 3</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="img/icon4.png">
    <h3>ICON 4</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="img/icon5.png">
    <h3>ICON 5</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="img/icon6.png">
    <h3>ICON 6</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you might have mistaken these alignement rules:align-items,*vertical when `flex-direction:row`, horizontal when `flex-direction:column`*  and justify-content *horizontal when `flex-direction:row`, vertical when `flex-direction:column`* - see if did not yet https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Your question is very unlcear with what should be centered and how

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**:

The reason why you're solution didnt work is because you were just aligning the items. Whereas you needed to align the content as well as justify the content to the center. furthermore, i have added flex direction in columns as your items are all one under the other - it will help with responsiveness when you want to adjust it later on.

**Try the following**:

```css
.services{
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
    align-content: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="subSection services">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="img/icon1.png">
    <h3>ICON 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="img/icon2.png">
    <h3>ICON 2</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="img/icon3.png">
    <h3>ICON 3</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="img/icon4.png">
    <h3>ICON 4</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="img/icon5.png">
    <h3>ICON 5</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="img/icon6.png">
    <h3>ICON 6</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mi augue, viverra sit amet ultricies</p>
  </div>
</div>
```